# Is it possible to modify the server to re-validate an expired certificates stored in the client?

Tags: ios, https, alamofire

I am writing an iOS app which is using Certificates Pinning to verify against the self-signed certificates sent from my server. However, the certificate in the client expired.

To by more specific, I am using Alamofire, and the configuration is:

```
let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            endpoint: .PinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true
            )
        ]
```

I have tested, if I changed `validateCertificateChain` to false, everything wil be fine again. However, its a published iOS app and I can not change anything.

If there is any thing I can do on the server to re-validate my certificate?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't solve that problem on the server side if the **certificate** is pinned.

If you pinned the **key** then you can ask for a new certificate with the same private key.

Keep in mind that using an expired certificate is dangerous because it definitively disabled the revocation check.

What you can do:

1. Ask for a new certificate with the same private key
2. Check if it work with your old client
3. If not, publish a new version of your client.